# How to use Microsoft Live Connect with multple users in wp7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-connect-sdk

I'm upgrading my wp7 app to allow profiles so that more than one person can use it. In the profile options you can create a basic account or use a Windows Live account. As I understand the live connect sdk, if I use the scope with offline access then the SignIn button saves the info so that the user doesn't have to keep logging in and giving their consent. This works great for one user but when I have multiple windows live users I have to sign the previous user out. By doing this the next user then has to go through the login process again.

Is there anyway I can set my app so that when any persons clicks their profile they login to their live account without going through the login process again? Maybe somehow save the session or something for each user?